# Unethical approach by agencies

Tags: recruitment

Can a recruitment agency continue to approach candidates that they have recently placed with an employer and charged a placement fee for?

Comment: "Can" they in what sense? I mean, yes - they "can" do anything. However, it's not a good practice, and many recruiting contracts are written such that the payment is only made after the employee has been employed for a certain period, to prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: Is it possible you're getting automated emails from recruiters about new jobs? Or are those you are getting clearly aimed at you specifically?

Comment: Thank you - I always thought that there was a code of ethics which prevented and recruiter from approaching previously placed empoyees with higher salaries etc within a period of time.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as "unclear what you're asking" because [there is no actual problem to be solved](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [the question is just a rant in disguise - "it's unethical for agencies to do that, am I right?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Sure, no problem here

Comment: I voted to close this because a) there's no problem to address and b) this is very dependant on the specific recruiter and their contract with the company they recruit for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, getting placed doesn't necessarily remove you from their contact list.

You can always respond and tell them that you're no longer looking for further placements and ask them not to contact you again.

You may need to repeat this request, as people may forget to remove you from the list (or only remove you from one of many lists/databases).

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a specific clause in their contract with the employer preventing such approaches then yes they can.

They generally don't though - not so much because of ethics but because it's a really low return. People who have recently placed are generally unlikely to want to change again so soon, unless of course they are really unhappy with the new role in which case it's not really the *recruiter's* fault if they choose to move on.